# AngularJS - Change iframe src after load

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iframe, angularjs-scope

I am having an iframe popup in my application whose src value is binded to data.videoUrl.I am using it as

```
data.videoUrl = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(data.videoUrl); //in controller
<iframe ng-src={{data.videoUrl}}/> //in template
```

When i try to change the iframe src in the controller by modifying data.videoUrl, it doesnt reflect in the popup.I am assuming it is because of ng-src as the other changes get reflected immediately.

How to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

you must use $scope module to assign videoUrl variable. If you use $scope any changes can be reflected to the view side.

Comment: The issue is not with binding.It happens only for iframe src for which i use ng-src. Other changes are getting reflected as expected.

Comment: Did you try to use video tag instead of iframe?